# How do I change the clock speed of an STM32 using PlatformIO with Arduino framework?

Tags: stm32

To reduce power consumption of the STM32 (F103C8), I would like to decrease the clock speed to 8 Mhz. I am using PlatformIO to compile some Arduino-based code for an STM32 (F103C8). By default, the Arduino framework sets the MCU to run at it's maximum clock speed of 72 MHz; `F_CPU` is `72000000L`.

I tried editing the `platformio.ini` file, adding the following line:

```
board_build.f_cpu = 8000000L
```

However, judging by the value of the `F_CPU` preprocessor macro, this appears to have made no difference; when compiled, the code still produces the value, `72000000L`.

I am familiar with how to change the clock speed in STM32CubeIDE, but would like to know how to do this in PlatformIO.

Comment: Might hold the key: https://community.platformio.org/t/clock-pll-divider-multiplier-overide-in-the-project-files-with-arduino-framework/22166